Should I enter the non-adjusted cost basis or the adjusted cost basis in Box 1e in Form 1099‑B in TurboTax for ESPP (Employee Stock Purchase Plan)?
I'm filing my taxes in the US since I reside in WA state and I'm being asked by TurboTax to enter  "Box 1e - Cost or other basis Learn more" for some Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP) stocks I sold last year via E-Trade.
E-Trade's Stock Plan Transactions Supplement document mentions both "Cost Basis" and "Adjusted Cost Basis", as shown below. Which one should I enter in Box 1e in Form 1099‑B in TurboTax?
Note that the Adjusted Cost Basis is higher than the Cost Basis, since these ESPP stock were originally purchased with an employee discount.


By default, TurboTax prefills "Box 1e - Cost or other basis Learn more" with the non-adjusted Cost Basis:


I think you want to enter the (unadjusted) cost basis, then check the 'The cost basis is incorrect or missing on my 1099-B' box underneath it.

I followed Craig W's comment:

I think you want to enter the (unadjusted) cost basis, then check the 'The cost basis is incorrect or missing on my 1099-B' box underneath it.

which seems to be correct, since afterward I was asked to enter the adjusted cost basis:

Note that the difference between the non-adjusted cost basis and the adjusted cost basis can be viewed in the W2 form Box 14, ESPP, since it corresponds to the employer's discount, which is taxed as ordinary income:

